# Subquery returned more than 1 value - SQL Error

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables : DISPO, ARTICLE & GCLIGNARTDIM

```
DISPO & ARTICLE linked by : DISPO.GQ_ARTICLE = ARTICLE.GA_ARTICLE 
ARTICLE & GCLIGNARTDIM linked by : ARTICLE.GA_CODEARTICLE = GCLIGNARTDIM.GL_CODEARTICLE
```

I want to display stock of each article from DISPO, and Sales of this Products from GCLIGNARTDIM. So i'm Using a subquery [Sales] to bring sales for previous 6 months.

```
SELECT GA_CODEARTICLE AS 'CODE ARTICLE',
    CC2.CC_LIBELLE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (GQ_DEPOT='001') THEN (GQ_PHYSIQUE) else 0 END) AS 'STOCK DEPOT',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (GQ_DEPOT='002') THEN (GQ_PHYSIQUE) else 0 END) AS 'STOCK STORE',

    [SALES] = 
    (SELECT
    SUM(GL_QTEFACT)AS 'QTE VENDUS'

    FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN PARPIECE GPP1 ON GL_NATUREPIECEG=GPP1.GPP_NATUREPIECEG AND GPP1.GPP_MASQUERNATURE<>'X' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CHOIXCOD CC2 ON GL_FAMILLENIV1=CC2.CC_CODE AND CC2.CC_TYPE='FN1'

    WHERE

    DATEADD(M, 6, GP_DATEPIECE) > getdate()
    AND CC2.CC_LIBELLE <> 'MARKETING'  AND GA_CODEARTICLE NOT LIKE 'T%' AND CC2.CC_LIBELLE <> 'ATELIER DE BEAUTé'

    GROUP BY GL_CODEARTICLE

    )

    FROM DISPO

    LEFT JOIN ARTICLE B ON GA_ARTICLE=GQ_ARTICLE 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPOTS GDE1 ON GQ_DEPOT=GDE1.GDE_DEPOT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CHOIXCOD CC2 ON GA_FAMILLENIV1=CC2.CC_CODE AND CC2.CC_TYPE='FN1'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CHOIXCOD CC4 ON GA_FAMILLENIV2=CC4.CC_CODE AND CC4.CC_TYPE='FN2'

    WHERE (
    (GQ_DEPOT IN ('001','002') AND CC2.CC_LIBELLE is not null and CC2.CC_LIBELLE <> 'MARKETING'  AND GA_CODEARTICLE NOT LIKE 'T%' AND CC2.CC_LIBELLE <> 'ATELIER DE BEAUTé'
    ))
    GROUP BY GA_CODEARTICLE,GA_CODEBARRE, CC2.CC_LIBELLE,CC4.CC_LIBELLE

    ORDER BY [CODE ARTICLE]
```

I'm getting an error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error message really couldn't be more clear... your sub-select ("SELECT SUM(GL_QTEFACT)…") is returning more than one row. You can't do that. Either fix the sub-query to return only the row you're really interested in, or fix corrupt data that is unexpectedly returning multiple rows where you're expecting only one.

Comment: you probably want to add `AND GCLIGNEARTDIM.GL_CODEARTICLE = DISPO.GA_CODEARTICLE` or something like that

Comment: How else could we make the error more clear to you???  Your subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: `    [SALES] = 
    (SELECT
    SUM(GL_QTEFACT)AS 'QTE VENDUS'

    FROM GCLIGNEARTDIM 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN PARPIECE GPP1 ON GL_NATUREPIECEG=GPP1.GPP_NATUREPIECEG AND GPP1.GPP_MASQUERNATURE<>'X' 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CHOIXCOD CC2 ON GL_FAMILLENIV1=CC2.CC_CODE AND CC2.CC_TYPE='FN1'

    WHERE

    DATEADD(M, 6, GP_DATEPIECE) > getdate()
    AND CC2.CC_LIBELLE <> 'MARKETING'  AND GA_CODEARTICLE NOT LIKE 'T%' AND CC2.CC_LIBELLE <> 'ATELIER DE BEAUTé'

    GROUP BY GL_CODEARTICLE

    )`  This sub query returns multiple result set means more than one row but only one is expected.

Answer (score 0):

This may help to understand the problem

```
   USE AdventureWorks2012
GO
-- This sub query will run as expected.
SELECT p.BusinessEntityID
      ,p.PhoneNumber 
      ,(SELECT Name FROM [Person].[PhoneNumberType] WHERE  PhoneNumberTypeID = p.PhoneNumberTypeID ) as  [Type] 
      -- This Sub Query returns one result against a row.
FROM  [Person].[PersonPhone] p
GO
-- This sub query will throw exception.
SELECT p.BusinessEntityID
      ,p.PhoneNumber 
      ,(SELECT Name FROM [Person].[PhoneNumberType] WHERE  PhoneNumberTypeID = p.PhoneNumberTypeID OR PhoneNumberTypeID = 1) as  [Type]
      -- This Sub Query returns more than one result against a row.
FROM  [Person].[PersonPhone] p
--Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
--Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```